# "undefined symbols for architecture" linker error when compiling a Qt tutorial

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I am getting an error when trying to compile my QT app on Mac. 
I followed this [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-diagramscene-example.html) all the code is at the bottom of the page.

When I build the project I get the following:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "DiagramItem::addArrow(Arrow*)", referenced from:
      DiagramScene::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent*) in diagramscene.o
  "DiagramScene::setItemType(DiagramItem::DiagramType)", referenced from:
      MainWindow::buttonGroupClicked(int) in mainwindow.o
      DiagramScene::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) in moc_diagramscene.o
  "DiagramScene::setTextColor(QColor const&)", referenced from:
      MainWindow::textButtonTriggered() in mainwindow.o
  "DiagramScene::setMode(DiagramScene::Mode)", referenced from:
      MainWindow::buttonGroupClicked(int) in mainwindow.o
      MainWindow::pointerGroupClicked(int) in mainwindow.o
      MainWindow::itemInserted(DiagramItem*) in mainwindow.o
      MainWindow::textInserted(QGraphicsTextItem&) in mainwindow.o
      DiagramScene::qt_static_metacall(QObject*, QMetaObject::Call, int, void**) in moc_diagramscene.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [DiagramScene.app/Contents/MacOS/DiagramScene] Error 1
18:41:52: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project DiagramScene (kit: Desktop)
When executing step 'Make'
```

Anyone seen this before or any suggestions?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Looks like you are failing to link in the file containing those symbols. Firstly find their implementation file and check the build logs that it is being compiled and linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linker is telling you exactly what's happening. There are no implementations provided for the methods that are listed, namely for:

- DiagramItem::addArrow(Arrow*)
- DiagramScene::setItemType(DiagramItem::DiagramType)
- DiagramScene::setTextColor(QColor const&)
- DiagramScene::setMode(DiagramScene::Mode)

Simply write the *implementations* of those methods. The example might be incomplete if you were copy-pasting the code from the help page.